# Proof using properties of determinants

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I have to use properties of determinants to show that

$$\left| \begin{array}{ccc}
b^2+c^2 & ab & ac \\
ab & a^2+c^2 & bc \\
ac & bc & a^2+b^2 \end{array} \right| = 4a^2b^2c^2$$

I am tempted to start by reducing the above expression to

By dividing respective rows by a,b,c and multiplying respective columns by a,b,c, 
$$\left| \begin{array}{ccc}
b^2+c^2 & b^2 & c^2 \\
a^2 & c^2+a^2 & c^2 \\
a^2 & b^2 & a^2+b^2 \end{array} \right|$$

and it's a road-bock ahead.

**Please provide a hint**. I would appreciate if you don't provide the whole solution, but just a hint.

Comment: Sarrus' rule (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_Sarrus)? Multiplying at most $b^2 + c^2, c^2 + a^2, a^2 + b^2$ seems okay for me...

Comment: No, it has to be better than that!

Comment: I do not understand how did you get that second form from first one...

Comment: Dividing respective rows by a,b,c and multiplying respective columns by a,b,c.

Comment: I have a strong suspicion that the mere definition of determinant is largely sufficient. Your trick with multiplying and dividing columns and rows is quite neat, though=)

Comment: I have a method but I'm not sure if you're allowed to use it: 
Notice that the given determinant is a homogeneous  polynomial $P(a,b,c)$ with $3$ variables $a,b$ and $c$ and due to the obvious symmetry of the determinant this polynomial is symmetric. Now it's easy to see that $P(a,a,a)=4a^6$ then we have 
$$P(a,b,c)=4a^2b^2c^2$$

Comment: @Sami It might very well be something (up to a constant factor) of the form $ab^3c^2+bc^3a^2+ca^3b^2+ba^3c^2+cb^3a^2+ac^3b^2$.

Comment: Yes you're right but with more work we can see that this polynomial doesn't contain a term with $a^3$ see  the second form of this determinant.@TZakrevskiy

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane well, it requires some of work. My next counterexample would be $a^4b^2+b^4c^2+c^4b^2$=)

Comment: Ok we can enumerate all the possible cases of counterexamples and then eliminate it one by one. For your counterexample we can see that the there's not a term that contains $a^4$ by developing (without doing calculus) the second determinant along the first column. Are there other counterexamples? ;-)@TZakrevskiy

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane I think we can stop here=) Anyway, if we develop the determinant along one of the columns, it's easier to find the said determinant just by definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to compute

$$
D=\left| \begin{array}{ccc}
y+z & y & z \\
x & x+z & z \\
x & y & x+y \end{array} \right|
$$

where $x=a^2,y=b^2,z=c^2$. You can proceed as follows :

$$
\begin{array}{lcl}
D &=& \frac{1}{x}\left| \begin{array}{ccc}
xy+xz & xy & xz \\
x & x+z & z \\
x & y & x+y \end{array} \right| \\
&=& \frac{1}{x}\left| \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & xy-y(x+z)-z(y) & xz-y(z)-z(x+y) \\
x & x+z & z \\
x & y & x+y \end{array} \right| \\
&=& -2yz\left| \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & x+z & z \\
1 & y & x+y \end{array} \right| \\
\end{array}
$$

Since you insist on not being provided the full solution, I stop here.

Comment: Oh! It became so much more apparent after the substitution.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** from the first situation of the determinant you need to calculate, notice that (for example) $b^2+c^2=(b+c)^2-2bc$. Than remember the property of addings columns\rows to each other.

Comment: lemme give it a shot

Answer (score 0):

If we don't want to use the definition of the determinant, we can obtain the final result from the second matrix you posted by adding/subtracting rows and columns; the goal is to eliminate the cells with sums of squares. I started by subtracting first and se cond column from the third one.